# Business Rules 'Get Started' in Bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, business-rules

I'm trying to test my sample ruleapp for Business Rules in Bluemix.  When I try to Test under the Decision Services tab in Business Rules I get the error 'Unable to run test.'

Comment: Post error you got

Comment: Error when extracting the ruleset parameter value from the request. No content to map due to end-of-input at [Source: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTInputStream@db02e30b; line: 1, column: 1]

Comment: Is your payload empty? There's a thread in BountySource that suggests some code included in Business Rules might throw an exception due to a lack of content - https://www.bountysource.com/issues/26156434-objectmapper-readvalue-inputstream-src-javatype-valuetype-raises-an-exception-on-empty-source